# Error when calling any method on Service Management API

Tags: c#, azure, azure-automation

I'm looking to start an Azure runbook from a c# application which will be hosted on an Azure web app.

I'm using certificate authentication (in an attempt just to test that I can connect and retrieve some data)

Here's my code so far:

```
var cert = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["mgmtCertificate"];

var creds = new Microsoft.Azure.CertificateCloudCredentials("<my-sub-id>",
new X509Certificate2(Convert.FromBase64String(cert)));

var client = new Microsoft.Azure.Management.Automation.AutomationManagementClient(creds, new Uri("https://management.core.windows.net/"));
var content = client.Runbooks.List("<resource-group-id>", "<automation-account-name>");
```

Every time I run this, no matter what certificate I use I get the same error:

`An unhandled exception of type 'Hyak.Common.CloudException' occurred in Microsoft.Threading.Tasks.dll`

`Additional information: ForbiddenError: The server failed to authenticate the request. Verify that the certificate is valid and is associated with this subscription.`

I've tried downloading the settings file which contains the automatically generated management certificate you get when you spin up the Azure account... nothing I do will let me talk to any of the Azure subscription

Am I missing something fundamental here?

**Edit: some additional info...**

So I decided to create an application and use the JWT authentication method.

I've added an application, given the application permissions to the Azure Service Management API and ensured the user is a co-administrator and I still get the same error, even with the token...

```
const string tenantId = "xx";
const string clientId = "xx";

var context = new AuthenticationContext(string.Format("https://login.windows.net/{0}", tenantId));

var user = "<user>";
var pwd = "<pass>";
var userCred = new UserCredential(user, pwd);

var result = context.AcquireToken("https://management.core.windows.net/", clientId, userCred);

var token = result.CreateAuthorizationHeader().Substring("Bearer ".Length);  // Token comes back fine and I can inspect and see that it's valid for 1 hour - all looks ok...

var sub = "<subscription-id>";
var creds = new TokenCloudCredentials(sub, token);
var client = new AutomationManagementClient(creds, new Uri("https://management.core.windows.net/"));

var content = client.Runbooks.List("<resource-group>", "<automation-id>");
```

I've also tried using other Azure libs (like auth, datacentre etc) and I get the same error:

`ForbiddenError: The server failed to authenticate the request. Verify that the certificate is valid and is associated with this subscription.`

I'm sure it's just 1 tickbox I need to tick buried somewhere in that monolithic Management Portal but I've followed a few tutorials on how to do this and they all end up with this error...

Comment: I've been using `ClientCredential` instead of `UserCredential`  http://www.cloudidentity.com/blog/2014/07/08/using-adal-net-to-authenticate-users-via-usernamepassword/

Comment: @MilenPavlov thanks for this but I've tried both using a Native app and a Web app with both a client credential (using a secret) and a user credential using a username/pass. I get the same issue with both (I successfully get a token, it just doesn't allow me to perform any operations)

Comment: I get not found exception on `var content = await client.Runbooks.ListByNameAsync("automationAccount", "runbookName", cancelationToken);`

Comment: @MilenPavlov are you having the same problem as me?

Comment: Found it in here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24999518/azure-api-the-server-failed-to-authenticate-the-request, just tested :)

Comment: Found that and tried that too with no luck :(

Comment: could post my code if you're interested?

Comment: Yes please, you didn't do anything special in the management portal did you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    public async Task StartAzureRunbook()
    {
        try
        {
            var subscriptionId = "azure subscription Id";
            string base64cer = "****long string here****"; //taken from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24999518/azure-api-the-server-failed-to-authenticate-the-request

            var cert = new X509Certificate2(Convert.FromBase64String(base64cer));

            var client = new Microsoft.Azure.Management.Automation.AutomationManagementClient(new CertificateCloudCredentials(subscriptionId, cert));
            var ct = new CancellationToken();

            var content = await client.Runbooks.ListByNameAsync("MyAutomationAccountName", "MyRunbookName", ct);


            var firstOrDefault = content?.Runbooks.FirstOrDefault();
            if (firstOrDefault != null)
            {
                var operation = client.Runbooks.Start("MyAutomationAccountName", new RunbookStartParameters(firstOrDefault.Id));
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
        }
    }
```

Also in portal:
1) Application is multitenant
2) Permissions to other applications section - Windows Azure Service Manager - Delegated permissions "Access Azure Service Management(preview)"

Comment: Thanks I'll give it a go and let you know

Comment: What version of the Azure API are you using? I don't have `ListByNameAsync` and it expects a `resourcegroupname` as the first param to the list methods..

Comment: `<package id="Microsoft.Azure.Management.Automation" version="0.15.2-preview" targetFramework="net452" />`

Comment: Ah right, after getting the preview version it all works! Annoying really as one of the tutorials on the MSDN said to use the latest pre-release, didn't think this would cause such an issue but apparently that's it! Thanks :)

Comment: Also works with the token based access method too... damn whole day of banging head against wall!

Answer (score 1):

Ensure that your Management certificate has private key and was not made from the .CER file.  The fact that you're not supplying a password when generating the X509Certificate object makes me think you're using public key only

Ensure that your Managemnet's certificate public key (.CER file) has been uploaded to the Azure management portal (legacy version, Management Certificate area)

Use CertificateCloudCredentials and not any other credential type of an object

Comment: I've tried using every credential type without success, including a certificate that I generated and a `.pfx` I generated and passed to the .NET app. I've even taken the default management certificate that you get when creating your subscription and used that (I can see in debug that all the certs I've used show `HasPrivateKey = true`) so I don't think it's this... why would using the token not work? Everything I've read says MS are phasing out certificate auth and are moving to token based... why do I get the same error there?

Comment: The answer lies in the cert.  Don't bother with other types of credentials.  This line new X509Certificate2(Convert.FromBase64String(cert)) tells me that the cert is made from public key.  What is "cert" string in the config file? Private keys require a decryption password

Comment: Yeah I've tried that too - I followed instructions which told me to upload the cert to Azure. I created a pfx from the cert and used an overload of new `X509Certificate2` which requires a password (I even tried getting the password wrong on purpose to make sure there was different behaviour in which case .NET threw an invalid password exception). I've followed every single walkthrough for all authentication methods and they all culminate in this error...

Comment: e.g. `new Microsoft.Azure.CertificateCloudCredentials(sub,
                new X509Certificate2(@"path-to-cert.pfx", "<password>"))` - using this credential which has been applied as a management cert on Azure portal still fails

Comment: Sorry for continuing to doubt, but over the years Iof supporting AzureWatch and CloudMonix, I've seen customers often  upload the cert either to wrong area or under wrong subscription. Can you double check that correct sub in the portal has the correct mgmt cert?

Comment: No problem I know how it is :) - I tried to browse directly to the management endpoint in Chrome and it asked me which cert I wanted to use in the request. I picked my cert (the popup showed "you have a private key that corresponds to this cert") and the response was: `<Message>
The server failed to authenticate the request. Verify that the certificate is valid and is associated with this subscription.
</Message>`. I only have 1 subscription :(

Comment: I've tried uploading the cert again just in case I'd uploaded the wrong cert and I get "failed to upload: the certificate already exists"

Comment: Checking in Fiddler to make sure the Auth header is present: `Authorization Header is present: Bearer <token string>`, so that looks fine... what am I missing here?

Answer (score 1):

Ok, stupid really but one of the tutorials I followed suggested installing the prerelease version of the libs.

Installing the preview (0.15.2-preview) has fixed the issue!